remote desktop - VNC not working properly
I have one pc with latest Ubuntu desktop (Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, gnome 46, windowing system x11, kernel Linux 6.8.0-48-generic) and other with Win11 (24H2), and I want to use a VNC to access Ubuntu machine from Win machine.
I have installed TightVNC server on Ubuntu machine and my .vnc/xstartup looks like this:
#!/bin/sh
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources 
unset SESSION_MANAGER 
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS 
startxfce4 &

When I connect on RealVNC viewer on my Win machine I can see the xfce desktop with icons, but when I want open folder, the folder opens at Ubuntu machine (I have monitor attached to it), but I see nothing on VNC. Weirdly enough, when I want to open for example task manager or htop in VNC I can see it in VNC... If I clicked on Firefox, the browser does not appear anywhere - nor in VNC, nor at Ubuntu machine...  What's wrong?
